# How can metamask create account on many networks?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

`MetaMask` is a browser extension that makes possible to have an ethereum account without run a full ethereum node.

I want to know how can metamsk create the account from my browser on many testnet like rposten, kovan without having an access to the network console. 
If is it allowed by an ethereum node, how to give metamsk right to create the account on my private ethereum node.

**NB**: my node is using **geth**

Answer (score 2):

Externally owned accounts (private key based addresses) are not tied to any node. Metamask can safely generate private keys and sign transactions with them without interacting with any node (although it does connect to nodes for gas estimates and nonces).

As long as the signature is valid for a particular chain, metamask can then connect to any available node on that chain and broadcast a signed transaction.